# Which works by Kang Youwei attack Empress Dowager Cixi?

Tags: resource, qing-dynasty

### Background

It is widely reported that [Kang Youwei](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kang_Youwei) and Liang Qichao bear the principal responsibility for the negative image of [Dowager Cixi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empress_Dowager_Cixi) as the reactionary who halted the 1898 reform. As far as Liang is concerned, I believe to have found a good sample of his views in the form of his work «戊戌政變記».

### Question

**Which works of Kang Youwei contain strong criticism of the Empress Dowager, especially as anti-reform minded?**. As I am not in China, works available online would be the most practical. I have tried to spot such titles in works *about* Kang, and found *[this](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.2753/CSH0009-4633250438?tab=permissions&scroll=top)* article, but I just don’t seem to be able to gain access.

Comment: Is this Wikipedia article of any use? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kang_Youwei

Comment: @Lesley I fear, no.